# How to remove empty icon space in Outlook menu

Tags: menu, outlook, icons, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating a menu hierarchy for an Outlook (2007) add-in. The menu items only have a caption -- no icons. However, there is still some (wasted) space reserved for an icon to the left of the captions. To get rid of the reserved space, I tried the obvious

```
Office.CommandBarButton button = parent.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true) as Office.CommandBarButton;
button.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
```

Which, I assumed, should have gotten rid of the space (in contrast to MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption, which should presumably reserve space for an icon), but it did not work (the empty space remains). How can I get rid of the space reserved for icons when there are no icons?

Furthermore, parent menu items (CommandBarPopup) also needlessly reserve space for icons, and they do not have a Style property. Is there a way to get rid of the icon space for these as well?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to remove the reserved space for icons, as the menu layout needs to support menu items with or without icons.